# How to count how many tabs are in a selection using Macro for formatting tables

Tags: vba, ms-word, format

I have to format a large document for a file that has been created from a PDF which is editable, so I know all the text is there.

The document is a series of tables. In Word the tables look pretty OK, but in some cases where there should be various cells there is just 1 and tabs have been used to align the text. So, it looks good, but if any of the text gets changed then the formatting will get messed up. I would like to have a macro that looks for cells with a tab, selects the cell, counts the number of tabs, divides the cell into the right number of cells and puts the text into the right cell. For example, a cell that contains "text 1 [tab]text 2[tab]text 3" would become 3 cells "text 1", "text 2" and "text 3".

I thought Word would be able to convert the text to a table, but when the text is already in a table it doesn't work.

If anyone has any suggestions as to how I might achieve this, then they would be much appreciated!

My main issue is not knowing how to count how many tabs are in a selection.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the number of Tabs in the given string.

```
Function CountTabs() As Integer

    Dim Txt     As String
    
    Txt = "This is" & vbTab & "a test" & vbTab & "to count Tabs"
    CountTabs = Len(Txt) - Len(Replace(Txt, vbTab, ""))
End Function
```

The tab character - Chr(9) - is replace with nothing and the number of tabs is the difference in character count before and after the replacement. Here is an implementation of the idea in a snippet.

```
Private Sub Snippet()
    Dim Txt     As String
    Dim Count   As Integer
    
    Txt = "This is" & vbTab & "a test" & vbTab & "to count Tabs"
    Count = Len(Txt) - Len(Replace(Txt, vbTab, ""))
    MsgBox "There are " & Count & " tabs."
End Sub
```

Of course, how you get the text for the variable `Txt` is another story and, in the context of this forum, another question. Prophylactically, I advise against using the `Selection` object, however. Try to use the `Range` object instead.